# How to dynamically filter a select2 listing based on option class

Tags: jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

I have a dropdown select of optional 'opportunities' (`id="opportunities"` in the example below) which I enhance using the [select2 jquery plugin](https://select2.github.io/), and wish to dynamically filter this list in order to reduce the possible options presented to a user using a 2nd select dropdown (`id="group-select"` in the example below),

```
<label>
  Select an opportunity<br>
  <select id="opportunities" style="width:300px;" multiple="multiple" name="selected-opps" value="">
    <optgroup label="Class A">
      <option class="group-1" value="1a">Opportunity 1a</option>
      <option class="group-2" value="2a">Opportunity 2a</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Class B">
      <option class="group-1" value="1b">Opportunity 1b</option>
      <option class="group-2" value="2b">Opportunity 2b</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Class C">
      <option class="group-1" value="1c">Opportunity 1c</option>
      <option class="group-2" value="2c">Opportunity 2c</option>
    </optgroup>
  </select>
</label>
<select id="group-select">
  <option value="">Select a group</option>
  <option value="group-1">group 1</option>
  <option value="group-2">group 2</option>
</select>
</div>
<div id="select-opportunity"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
(function( $ ) {
  'use strict';

   var opportunities = $('select#opportunities').select2({
    dropdownParent: $('#select-opportunity')
  });
})( jQuery );
</script>
```

I wish to be able to make a selection in the 2nd select, say 'group 1' and would like the select2 list to contain only 'group-1' items as per the option in the first select dropdown that have the `grouo-1` class attribute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to solve this using 2 optional functionality provided by the select2 plugin, namely the ability to control the way items are built and displayed using the [templating functionality](https://select2.org/dropdown#templating), and using the [programmatic control](https://select2.org/programmatic-control/methods) exposed in the plugin.  I replaced the javascript appended below the example in the question with,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function( $ ) {
  'use strict';

  var opportunities = $('select#opportunities').select2({
    dropdownParent: $('#select-opportunity'),
    templateResult: formatItem
  });
  function formatItem (state) {
    if (!state.id) { return state.text; }
    //change the id of our select2 items
    state._resultId = state._resultId+'-'+state.element.className;
    var $state = $(
      '<span class="opportunity-item ' + state.element.className + '">' + state.text + '</span>'
    );
    return $state;
  }
  $('select#group-select').change( function() {
    //hide the unwanted options
    var group = $('select#group-select option:selected').val();
    //clear the styling element
    $('style#select2-style').empty();

    if(group){
      //if a group is selected we need to hide all the others
      $('select#group-select option').not(':selected').each(function(){
        group = $(this).val();
        if(group){
          $('style#select2-style').append(
           'li[id$="'+group+'"]{display:none;}'
          );
        }
      });
    }
    //force the select2 to referesh by opening and closing it again
    opportunities.select2('open');
    opportunities.select2('close');
  });


})( jQuery );
</script>
<style id="select2-style"></style>
```

I have also added an empty `<style>` element at the bottom in which I dynamically create the rules required to hide the unwanted items.

### The logic

The code above creates templating function `formatItem` that the select2 plugin will use to format the items.  The item `state` object is passed to the function which includes the unique `id` for each item.

This `id` is modified by appending the class of the corresponding option element.

When a group option is selected in the 2nd dropdown select (`#group-select`) a set of styling is created and appended to the bottom `<style>` element to hide all the elements whose `id` attributes end with the class names to be hidden, for example if one seleced group-1, the code will create a style to hide group-2 items,

```
li[id$="group-2"] { 
  display:none;
}
```

However for this to work we need to force the select2 dropdown to refresh to pick up the new styling and the only way I found for this work was to use the programmatic control of the plugin to 'open' and immediately 'close' the select2 dropdown.

Answer (score -1):

> ّshort Example .

```
window.templateResult = function templateResult(state) {
            if (state.text.indexOf('ss') == -1)
                return null;///hide

            if (!state.id) { return state.text; }
            var $state = $(
              '<span>' + state.text + '</span>'
            );
            return $state;
        };

        //Init
        $("#select1").select2({
            templateResult: templateResult
        });
```

ّFull Example below.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

            //general custom filter
            window.Select2FilterFunc = function (state) { return "Default" };

            //general custom templateResult
            window.templateResult = function templateResult(state) {

                //call custom filter
                var result = Select2FilterFunc(state);
                if (result != "Default")
                    return result;

                if (!state.id) { return state.text; }
                var $state = $(
                  '<span>' + state.text + '</span>'
                );
                return $state;
            };

            //Init
            $("#select1").select2({
                templateResult: templateResult
            });

            //Add Custom Filter when  opening
            $('#select1').on('select2:opening', function (evt) {

                //set your filter
                window.Select2FilterFunc = function (state) {
                    if (state.text.indexOf('ss') == -1)
                        return null;//hide item
                    else
                        return "Default";
                };

            }).on('select2:close', function (evt) {
                window.Select2FilterFunc = function (state) { return "Default" };
            });

        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<select id="select1" class="js-states form-control" style="width:300px" multiple="multiple ">
        <optgroup label="Alaskan/Hawaiian Time Zone">
            <option value="AK" title="11111111">Alaska</option>
            <option value="HI" title="2222">Hawaii </option>
        </optgroup>
        <optgroup label="Pacific Time Zone">
            <option value="CA">California</option>
            <option value="NV">Nevada</option>
            <option value="OR">Oregon</option>
            <option value="WA">Washington</option>
        </optgroup>
        <optgroup label="Mountain Time Zone">
            <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
            <option value="CO">Colorado</option>
            <option value="ID">Idaho</option>
            <option value="MT">Montana</option>
            <option value="NE">Nebraska</option>
            <option value="NM">New Mexico</option>
            <option value="ND">North Dakota</option>
            <option value="UT">Utah</option>
            <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
        </optgroup>
        <optgroup label="Central Time Zone">
            <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
            <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
            <option value="IL">Illinois</option>
            <option value="IA">Iowa</option>
            <option value="KS">Kansas</option>
            <option value="KY">Kentucky</option>
            <option value="LA">Louisiana</option>
            <option value="MN">Minnesota</option>
            <option value="MS">Mississippi</option>
            <option value="MO">Missouri</option>
            <option value="OK">Oklahoma</option>
            <option value="SD">South Dakota</option>
            <option value="TX">Texas</option>
            <option value="TN">Tennessee</option>
            <option value="WI">Wisconsin</option>
        </optgroup>
        <optgroup label="Eastern Time Zone">
            <option value="CT">Connecticut</option>
            <option value="DE">Delaware</option>
            <option value="FL">Florida</option>
            <option value="GA">Georgia</option>
            <option value="IN">Indiana</option>
            <option value="ME">Maine</option>
            <option value="MD">Maryland</option>
            <option value="MA">Massachusetts</option>
            <option value="MI">Michigan</option>
            <option value="NH">New Hampshire</option>
            <option value="NJ">New Jersey</option>
            <option value="NY">New York</option>
            <option value="NC">North Carolina</option>
            <option value="OH">Ohio</option>
            <option value="PA">Pennsylvania</option>
            <option value="RI">Rhode Island</option>
            <option value="SC">South Carolina</option>
            <option value="VT">Vermont</option>
            <option value="VA">Virginia</option>
            <option value="WV">West Virginia</option>
        </optgroup>
    </select>
```

Comment: your answer doesn't seem to answer the question.  In you example you have not used any grouping/classification of options beyond the <optgroup>.  How to you filter the list based on 2 or more classification parameters?